# How to pull data from JIRA to create custom reports

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I'm trying to pull data from JIRA that would be valuable to a QA manager. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to see how many times an issue was tested, and sent back for development due to failing testing. I've browsed a bunch of plug-ins but I don't think I've come across one that can pull such specific data from JIRA and create a report. The other option I've come across is using the API's com.atlassian.jira.issue.changehistory methods to pull the data and then filter it using conditional statements in Java. However, I'd prefer a ready-made plug-in that can support such querying of JIRA data if one is available.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing your jira workflows and your level of knowledge about jira developement. There are couple of ways to get data out of jira (REST api, write your own report, SQL, use an exsting plugin from marketplace). What fits best for you depends on too many factors to give a general answer here.

Comment: I specifically need a report of issues with the number of times they were each tested (were "In QA" status). I can currently get all of the issues that went back from QA to Dev using a filter, but I can't get the number of times each issue went back to Dev without opening each issue individually and looking at its history and manually counting the number of times.

Comment: I have never tryed it myself, but maybe you have a look at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities. "Transitions summary" looks promising, although I am afraid it also only offers the functionality for one issue and not for a filter result.